# window on focus misbehave in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to call function when focusing on window or tab using jquery  $(window).focus function.

The problem is in mozilla the function is being called repeatedly or endlessly, while in chrome its behave normally (the function only called once when window focused).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).focus(function(){
      location.reload();
   });
});
```

Does any one had an alternative solution for mozilla.
Thank you, and Sorry for may bad english.

Im using mozilla version 36.0.1

Comment: Don't use `alert`, it's shown in a separate window, and when you click `OK` to close the alert window, the main window will get the focus again, and the alert is shown ... When logging to the console, your code [seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/xsdyLjuw/) in FF too.

Comment: actually im using alert as an example, my true purpose is reload the window when the window focuse. so my actual code is not alert, but location.reload(); but its still the same in mozilla it keep reloading endlesly, while in chrome it only reload once.

Comment: i have edited my question, thats my real code. It quite simple actually. I just want to reload the page once it focused.

Comment: It is always going to get focus so it is always got to get fired. What is the real goal, why do you need to reload it?

Comment: to simply put it, i want to reload it once it get focused is because, when the information on that page is edited on another page, so when i get back to that page it shows the latest information.
Lets take for an example its a blog feed page, so in another page i created a new article, i expect when i get back to the blog feed page it shows the latest article i just recently added on the other page.